# Selecting Closest Prior Year Cash From DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to select the cash (decimal) amount from the closest prior year (db column is called year, but is of DateTime type). This is giving me the cash from the year just input. Any suggestions for fixing my query?

```
ViewBag.priorYearCash =  ((from r in db.FinancialPeriods  
                           where r.Year.Year < financialPeriod.Year.Year
                           orderby financialPeriod.Year.Year descending
                           select financialPeriod.Cash)
                          .First()).ToString();
```

Thanks for any help,

Ruben

Comment: I assume you mean `orderby r.Year.Year descending` and `select r.Cash`

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to get with the query, could you please add more information

Comment: @StephenMuecke : that worked! How do I give you credit on here for answering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning the `Cash` value of the `financialPeriod` object your using to filter your query. It should be

```
ViewBag.priorYearCash =  ((from r in db.FinancialPeriods  
                           where r.Year.Year < financialPeriod.Year.Year
                           orderby r.Year.Year descending
                           select r.Cash)
                          .First()).ToString();
```

Side notes: calling `.ToString()` is probably not necessary, and you probably want to sort by the actual `DateTime` property, not the year to ensure you get the most recent value from the previous year - i.e.

```
orderby r.Year descending
```